# Is it possible to change line width in xmgrace only in legend?

Tags: xmgrace

I want to change line width in xmgrace, but only in legends. I can change length in legends (Graph Appearance -> Legends -> Legend Line length), but not width. I can change the width of the line but it also changes line width not only in legends, but also in line graph. How to do that only in legends?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that this can be done. However, as always with xmgrace you can find a dirty workaround.

- Create a new dataset in spreadsheet
- Add a single point (which won't be visible since the symbol type is set to None by default)
- Set the color to match the curve you want to write the legend for
- Add the correct legend (and remove it from the visible curve)
- Thicken the line as much as you want.

Here is an example:
[image]